# D-link router interupting Internet connection

Tags: encryption, wireless-networking

This message appeared on a wireless connected PC, then on the host Mac computer:

> Authentication Required
>   A user name and password are being requested by .... 
>   
>   The site says: RE1000

Was not able to obtain an Internet connection until I did a direct connect from the cable router to the Mac computer, disconnecting the wireless completely. But, the other computer is no longer able to connect to the Internet. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You should install DD-WRT. It fixed many issue with my D-link firmware.